# Name That ...Name? #7

Tags: riddle, knowledge

My name can be given in a male or female place

I sound like a lens better than a hand one to your face

Come from a crooked river in a misty highlands

I am one of the only cougars that has a lot of fans

Name That Name

Update: I messed up with the first line, now it should make sense. Sorry

Comment: For the life of me I cannot parse the second line; should there be some punctuation, or is it just very cryptic?

Comment: It's meant to be cryptic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name is

> Cameron

My name can be given in a male or female place

> Cameron can be a male or female name

I sound like a lens better than a hand one to your face

> Kinda sounds like "camera on", a camera uses a different lens than the glasses you wear.

Come from a crooked river in a misty highlands

> The [Cameron River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cameron_River) is in New Zealand, coming from Mount Arrowsmith in the southern alps.

I am one of the only cougars that has a lot of fans

> Cameron Diaz has dated a few younger men and is considered a cougar because of it. She's a famous actress and has a lot of fans.

Comment: Correct, good job

Answer (score 1):

Is your name

> Victoria?

My circulation keeps going even in the coldest place

> There are several [Victoria Rivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victoria_River), including one in Antarctica (the coldest place).

I sound like a lens better than a hand one to your face

> Not sure yet.

Come from a crooked river in a misty highlands

> [Victoria Falls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victoria_Falls) comes from the crooked [Zambezi River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zambezi) which starts in a misty African highlands.

I am one of the only cougars that has a lot of fans

> I forcefit my answers to be Victoria because when I saw this clue, I first thought of [Victoria Beckham aka Posh Spice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victoria_Beckham).

Comment: Good guess, but no